# Leaflet Multipolyline with dynamic rings

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dynamic-arrays

for the usage of multipolylines with leaflet, i have to instantiate the polyline like this...

```
var polyline = L.polyline([[], []], {color: generateRandomColor()}).addTo(map);
```

How do i instantiate the polyline with a dynamic quantity of rings(empty arrays)?

How can i do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which loops X times and adds empty arrays:

```
function createRings(rings){
    var latlngs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < rings || 0; i++){
        latlngs.push([]);
    }
    return latlngs;
}

var polyline = L.polyline(createRings(3), {color: generateRandomColor()}).addTo(map);
```